# Delphi 2007 Version Info missing from Exe

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, dunit

I have a Delphi 2007 project and I'm trying to set the Project->Options->'Version Info'. I enter the values into the form and save the project. However, when I build, the generated exe doesn't contain the Version Info that I entered. In fact, it only contains the File Version, Language and Product Version - none of the other values like Internal name, Product name etc...

I noticed that the values do not get saved to the .dproj file. So I tried entering them manually into the xml of said file, saving, and building. Again, the Version Info is incomplete for the exe.

By Version Info (in Windows), I mean what you see when you right-click on the exe and choose properties and click on the Version tab.

**EDIT:**
I should probably also mention that this is a Test project using DUnit.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC those values are still saved in the .res file. Are you deleting/modifying it someway?

Comment: They are and deleting the .res file could solve the problem, this also removes your application icon though.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the .res file, as a last resort you could delete the .dproj file, Delphi can recreate it from the .dpr file, but you lose your complete build configuration settings and they will be reset to defaults.

Comment: I have deleted both the res and the dproj file. Re-opened the project and re-built to generate exe. No change. I really think this is something to do with DUnit, that my test project is running under a DUnit application.

Comment: Quite possible the DUnit framework contains two .res files as well (DUnit.res and versioninfo.res). Why do you want to set version information on a DUnit project anyway?

Comment: One of the tests that I have sends file version information of the active application to a central server for version tracking. The test fails because the exe that runs the test has no version information.

Comment: Then you also have the problem to keep the version information of your real exe and the test project in sync.

Comment: To add version information to a DUnit test runner you probably have to modify the DUnit source code.